# Session lost when click on javascript generate link asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am making a website that has a shopping basket feature and I am using the session to store the shopping cart. When I navigate through the site it works fine and displays the number of items in the basket, but when I click on a link that is create by a javascript function it loses the variable on the session. It only causes this problem on the links generated by javascript

Adding item code

```
    if (context.Session["jobBasket"] == null)
    {
        context.Session.Add("jobBasket", new System.Collections.ArrayList());
    }
    var list = context.Session["jobBasket"] as System.Collections.ArrayList;
    var item = int.Parse(context.Request["jobId"]);
    if (!list.Contains(item))
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
```

Comment: How are you storing the variable in the session? Can you post some code that shows how stuff is being stored?

Comment: please see my edit, page is not opened in new window

Comment: Hi @Mike Norgate could you post an example of the rendered html / javascript please?

Comment: Check if the session cookie is different between the working/non-working links. If it's different, then you're getting a new blank session and something's not setting the cookie right to begin with.

Comment: After a bit more investigating, the session value seems to be getting lost after the page has loaded, because the count displays the first time the page is loaded but the when I reload the page the variable is lost, but I have no references to session anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

Are sessions even enabled for your app? for instance - if you have a single page that reads, updates, and prints out the value - does it stay? if not your session is potentially disabled or configured odd, check your web.config